# How to use exception in python(examples)

Tags: python

There are two examples from MITx: 6.00.1x. The first one is:

```
def fancy_divide(list_of_numbers, index):
    try:
        try:
            raise Exception("0")
        finally:
            denom = list_of_numbers[index]
            for i in range(len(list_of_numbers)):
                list_of_numbers[i] /= denom
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
```

When I call fancy_divide([0, 2, 4], 0), it shows: division by zero.

The second example is:

```
def fancy_divide(list_of_numbers, index):
    try:
        try:
            denom = list_of_numbers[index]
            for i in range(len(list_of_numbers)):
                list_of_numbers[i] /= denom
        finally:
            raise Exception("0")
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
```

When I call fancy_divide([0, 2, 4], 0), it shows: 0

Why do they have different results?

Comment: There's nothing to describe. Have you understood what `try` and `finally` is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def fancy_divide(list_of_numbers, index):
    ''' As soon as the function is called, interpreter executes the 2nd try block raising Exception('0')
    Since an exception is raised, finally block would get excuted.
    Since we passed denom value being zero, Interpreter throws a divide by zero error'''
    try:
        try:
            raise Exception("0") # exception is raised
        finally:
            denom = list_of_numbers[index] # finally executed because of exception
            for i in range(len(list_of_numbers)):
                list_of_numbers[i] /= denom # Divide by zero Error thrown by interpreter
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
```

---

```
def fancy_divide(list_of_numbers, index):
    '''You don't require explanation if you understood previous one'''
    try:
        try: 
            denom = list_of_numbers[index]
            for i in range(len(list_of_numbers)):
                list_of_numbers[i] /= denom # Divide by zero Exception is thrown by interpreter
        finally:
            raise Exception("0") # Raises Exception("0")
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex) # prints the same
```

Comment: why didn't the first one execute the "except Exception as ex:"

Comment: @jiangniao it executed `except Exception as ex:` Since interpreter thrown a **Divide by zero** exception, `except Exception as ex` caught and printed that exception.